# Can we use Amazon AWS boto3 from cloud based python IDE?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

The default location of the boto3 credentials and config file can be changed using these attributes `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` and `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` in your machine (Mac, Unix/Linux, Win) :   source: 
 http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html

But is there any way to use Amazon AWS boto3 from cloud based python IDE ?

**EDIT**

Yes, I can install boto3 using pip but I am not able to access services like `EC2` and `S3` of Amazon AWS 
 
 I am using IBM's cloud based python IDE https://my.datascientistworkbench.com

Comment: is the default location the only way how to provide credentials and config?

Comment: which IDE might be helpful to get an answer.

Comment: boto3 is a Python library. It will be used by your Python app. Can your 'cloud based python IDE' can run Python code that you supply and can it install additional Python libraries (eg `pip install boto3`)?